# Select Record With Higher Value

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have the following table:

```
+-----+---------+-------+
| ID  | Account | Score |
+-----+---------+-------+
|   1 |       1 |  500  |
|   2 |       1 |  200  |
|   3 |       2 |  150  |
|   4 |       2 |  200  |
|   5 |       3 |  100  |
|   6 |       3 |  100  |
|   7 |       4 |  300  |
+-----+---------+-------+
```

What I want my query to do is check the table to see if any accounts match.  If they do, then check the Score and see which is higher.  Output the record with the higher score.  If the scores are the same, output the ID that is first.  If there are no accounts that match, just output the record.

The output would look like this:

```
+-----+---------+-------+
| ID  | Account | Score |
+-----+---------+-------+
|   1 |       1 |  500  |
|   4 |       2 |  200  |
|   5 |       3 |  100  |
|   7 |       4 |  300  |
+-----+---------+-------+
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is at least two ways to do this. One with a derived table, and one with a CTE. These two queries assume there aren't two accounts with the same score. If that's a possibility, we can use another method to get the last ID, or pick a random one.

```
;select 
    t.ID
    ,t2.Account
    ,t2.Score
from
    YourTable t
inner join
    (select Account, Score = max(Score)
    from YourTable
    group by Account) t2 on t2.Account = t.Account and t2.Score = t.Score;


;with cte as(
    select RN = row_number() over (partition by Account order by Score desc, id)
            *,
    from YourTable)

select
    ID,
    Account,
    Score
from cte
where RN = 1;
```

Comment: You can use `over (... order by Score desc, id)` in your window function solution, to meet the requirements for ties. I edited (and added some missing terminators ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, there are going to be accounts that have the same score.  The Score column is a credit score, which anyone could potentially have the same score as someone else. @ypercubeᵀᴹ

Comment: Phil @ypercubeᵀᴹ explained how to get around that in the edit

Comment: Ah, still somewhat of an SQL noob.  I'll try this out.  Thanks!

Comment: yes, the second query resolves the ties (highest score, lower id in case of same score). The 1st query shows all tied results.